# Expected Value and Fubini

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, expected-value

I found this while searching for the Integralform of the Expected value:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccxdN.png)

Unfortunately I can't really understand the steps, can someone help me? Would be cool if you could explain it from the other direction, starting with the last step, that's the way I would show it in my proof.

Best, KingDingeling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal is to invert exchange the two integrals, this is because the term in the middle is only a function of $y$. So you have :
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^\infty \int_{x}^{\infty} f_X(y) dy dx&=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^{\infty} f_X(y) \mathbf 1_{(y\geq x)} dy dx\\
&=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^{\infty} f_X(y) \mathbf 1_{(y\geq x)} dx dy\\
&=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^{y} f_X(y) dx dy
\end{align*}

Going from the first to the second line is only swapping the integrals from $x$ then $y$ to $y$ then $x$, you can do this in general if the function you integrate is absolutely integrable but this may be done for some other cases. The first and the last steps correspond to the application of the indicator function to the inner integral.

EDIT : the other direction is exactly taking the steps backward and  so it is the same in the end
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^{y} f_X(y) dx dy&=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^{\infty} f_X(y) \mathbf 1_{(y\geq x)} dx dy\\
&=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{0}^{\infty} f_X(y) \mathbf 1_{(y\geq x)} dy dx\\
&=\int_{0}^\infty \int_{x}^{\infty} f_X(y) dy dx
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much. I have problems understanding the first step of the "other direction". I know this might be annoying but it would be very kind if you could explain it. I don't get the very first step.

Comment: The first integral is over $y$, the second is over $x$ and going from $0$ to $y$, so it is the same as taking the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ and considering only those $x\in [0,y]$, this is enforced by the indicator function.

Comment: Thank you very very much. Very kind to answer so quickly and well explained.